# Fetching resource through https not working in dev server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform

I have some pretty plain code that fetches a resource from an appengine project. This code is running in another project also hosted in appengine.

When deployed, the code runs without problems, but when I run it using the dev server, I always endup getting a SSLHandshakeException: Peer not authenticated.

```
try {
  URL url = new URL("https://host-name/path/to/stuff");

  try {
    InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();

    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

    String line;
    while((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
      //do stuff
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    //I end up here
  }
```

I have tried the same exact code with https://www.google.com and others and there's no problem. I have also set up a local https server, configured with the same certificate and the code runs as expected. Opening the url using the browser also works and chrome reports no problems with the certificate.

I am using "SNI only" as the serving mode for my domain and it's a wildcard DV certificate.

Any clues on what the problem may be?

Comment: Hi Pedro! I am investigating this, but I think this might be a good candidate for our issue tracker (since it possibly could be a problem with the SDK). Do you mind reposting your question here? https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues. Once you do, one of the support team guys will make the issue private so we can get the address you're trying to hit and investigate further. Thanks :)

Comment: Done. Thank you. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12108&thanks=12108&ts=1435827953